# Separating Tkinter UI concerns from Logic in Python app

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit, separation-of-concerns

This is my first app ever. It is working well but I would like to separate the UI concerns like getting input and creating labels, from the translation logic. I would then like to remove the output from the previous translation, i.e., only showing one translation on the screen at a time.

How can I separate the translation logic from my Tkinter GUI?

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox


def start():
    inputg = input.get()
    if len(inputg) >= 2 and inputg.isalpha():
        new_word_out = Label(text=(inputg[1:] + (inputg[0] + "ay")).lower().title()).pack()
        out_message = Label(text="Cool! Try another!").pack()
        # restart()
    elif len(inputg) <= 1 and inputg.isalpha():
        show_error(message="Whoops! I need 2 or more characters to translate! Try again!")
        return
    elif len(inputg) >= 1 and not inputg.isalpha():
        show_error(message="Whoops! No numbers or symbols please! Try again!")
        return
    elif len(inputg) == 0:
        show_error(message="It seems you haven't given me anything to translate!")
        return


def show_error(message):
    tkMessageBox.showerror(title="Error", message=message)
    return


def quit():
    ask_exit = tkMessageBox.askyesno(title="Quit", message="Are you sure you want to quit?")
    if ask_exit > 0:
        root.destroy()
        return


root = Tk()
input = StringVar()  # stores user input into this variable as a string.

root.title("The Pig Translator")

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", quit)

labeltitle1 = Label(text="Hello there! This is my Pig Latin Translator!").pack()

labeltitle2 = Label(text="Please enter a word to continue!", fg='darkgreen', bg='grey').pack()

original_entry = Entry(textvariable=input, bd=5, fg='darkgreen').pack()

translate_button = Button(text="Translate", command=start).pack()
root.bind('<Return>', lambda event: start())  # essentially binds 'Return' keyboard event to translate_button

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question -- In your code, `labeltitle1` will have the value of `None` since `Widget.pack` returns `None`.  I've seen this one bite too many people to not comment on it ... :-)

Comment: Related: [Program freezing during the execution of a function in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10847626/3357935)

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways you can separate logic from GUI. generally I would recommend using classes and callback functions. Thus, I made a class that generates the gui. However, the translation is performed by external function called `do_translation`.

MyFrame does not know much about how `do_translation`. It only knows it returns `translated_str, message` and takes string as argument. `do_translation` does not relay on any gui as well.  The `do_translation` takes only an input string, does what it wants, and returns translated string and message. The MyFrame take this function as a callback. You can make any other translation function, and as long as the input and output are same, it will work.

I rely here on a "Cool" in a massage which indicates that translation was ok. Its poor idea to make it relay on 'Cool' word, but did not want to change your code too much. Probably better to raise some error, or use message codes, etc.

```
from Tkinter import *

import tkMessageBox


class MyFrame(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, input_callback=None, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.set_input_callback(input_callback)
        self.create_widgets()
        self.pack()

    def create_widgets(self):

        self.input = StringVar()  # stores user input into this variable as a string.

        self.labeltitle1 = Label(text="Hello there! This is my Pig Latin Translator!")
        self.labeltitle1.pack()

        self.labeltitle2 = Label(text="Please enter a word to continue!", fg='darkgreen', bg='grey')
        self.labeltitle2.pack()

        self.original_entry = Entry(textvariable=self.input, bd=5, fg='darkgreen')
        self.original_entry.pack()

        self.translate_button = Button(text="Translate", command=self.start)
        self.translate_button.pack()

        self.new_word_out = Label(text='')
        self.out_message = Label(text='')

    def set_input_callback(self, some_fun):
        self.input_callback = some_fun

    def show_error(self, message):
        tkMessageBox.showerror(title="Error", message=message)
        return

    def start(self):
        inputg = self.input.get()

        if self.input_callback:

            translated_str, message = self.input_callback(inputg)

            if 'Cool' in message:
                self.new_word_out['text'] = translated_str
                self.new_word_out.pack()
                self.out_message['text'] = message
                self.out_message.pack()

            else:
                self.show_error(message)


def do_translation(inputg):
    translated_str = message = ''

    if len(inputg) >= 2 and inputg.isalpha():
        translated_str = (inputg[1:] + (inputg[0] + "ay")).lower()
        message = "Cool! Try another!"
    elif len(inputg) <= 1 and inputg.isalpha():
        message = "Whoops! I need 2 or more characters to translate! Try again!"
    elif len(inputg) >= 1 and not inputg.isalpha():
        message = "Whoops! No numbers or symbols please! Try again!"
    elif len(inputg) == 0:
        message = "It seems you haven't given me anything to translate!"

    return translated_str, message


def quit():
    ask_exit = tkMessageBox.askyesno(title="Quit", message="Are you sure you want to quit?")
    if ask_exit > 0:
        root.destroy()
        return


root = Tk()

root.title("The Pig Translator")
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", quit)

mf = MyFrame(root)
mf.set_input_callback(do_translation)

root.bind('<Return>', lambda event: start())  # essentially binds 'Return' keyboard event to translate_button

root.mainloop()
```

Hopefully this will be useful. I know, that there is not too much explanation what is happening here, but, don't have much time to write it. Your problem is very general.