# How to show the current window in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Hope you can help me with the following issue.

I'm using the library tkinter and
I have a main_screen `main_screen= Tk()` which is looping with `mainloop()`

Inside of the main_screen, there is a little data form where you need to type some necessary data.
And at the end of the window, I have a button to open a second window.

Once I click in that button, report_screen appears (See below in my code)

The new window should appear with the command `Toplevel()` and print a label that says Starting:

`request_start = LabelFrame(report_screen, text="Starting...").pack()`

then my program must run a process where it takes around 10 seconds to complete it.

Let's suppose that my process is just this

`time.sleep(10)`

And finally, run the next line:

`request_done = LabelFrame(report_screen, text="Done").pack()`

**What is my problem?**

The problem is that `report_screen` doesnt appear until the process of 10 sec has finished, and appears with both labels "Starting..." and "Done" at the same time.

I don't want  that, I require that `report_screen` appears with the label "Starting", and then run the process, and when the process finished, add the "Done" label

This is the part of my code where I have this issue

```
report_screen = Toplevel()

request_start = Label(report_screen, text="Starting...").pack()

time.sleep(10) #example of my process that takes around 10 seconds

request_done = Label(report_screen, text="Done").pack()
```

Comment: `time.sleep(10)` does exactly what it says: it puts the entire application to sleep. There are countless questions on this site related to calling `time.sleep(...)` in a tkinter app.

Comment: @BryanOakley, I know that but my process is not `time.sleep`, I just put it as an example that my real process takes around 10 sec

Comment: like most GUI mechanisms, it runs an event loop (aka mainloop) and if that is not allowed to cycle, screen updates will not happen.  try `report_screen.update_idletasks()` after the first update and before your task.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860302/python-tkinter-about-calling-a-long-running-function-that-freeze-the-progra help?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Nicely Done, seems that `update()` method works fine to update whatever is in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Using `update()` method works to update whatever is in the screen